# C++ Mysql Variable Insert

Tags: c++, mysql, database, variables, insert

My Structure:

```
long int uuId;
short int cameraNo;
```

Statement:

```
pstmt = con -> prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Amts(UUID,KameraNo) VALUES("<< first.uuId <<"," << first.cameraNo <<");");
```

I have wrote this code but it's not works on c++, how can i insert these variables into database?

Error:

> main.cpp:72:48: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [79]’ and
>   ‘long long int’ to binary ‘operator<<’

**Edit:**

```
prepStmt = con -> prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Amts VALUES (?,?)");

        prepStmt -> setInt(1,first.uuId);
        prepStmt -> setInt(2,first.cameraNo);

        prepStmt -> executeUpdate();
```

This code has worked successfully but if i am not sure about using long variable inside of setInt

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: details please. What doesn't work, what is the ERROR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
long int uuId;
short int cameraNo;
std::stringstream s;
s << "INSERT INTO Amts(UUID,KameraNo) VALUES("<< first.uuId <<"," << first.cameraNo  <<");";
pstmt = con -> prepareStatement(s.str());
```

Comment: There is no error, but it doesn't affects database, also cout << s.str(); prints nothing.